# How to format a string date (with text and milliseconds) using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I'm working on an AWK script that parses millions of lines of text. Each line contains (among other things) a date & time on the form:

```
16-FEB-2008 14:17:59.994669
```

I need to convert this into the following form

```
20080216141759994669000
```

And I would like avoid translating the month from text into a numerical value manually if it's possible. In bash I can simply do the following command to get the desired result:

```
date -d "16-FEB-2008 14:17:59.994669" +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N"
```

I have tried invoking this command into AWK but I cannot figure out howto. I would like to know

1. Is it possible to achieve with AWK alone?
2. How can I use such a command in an AWK script file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Running command `date...` milions of times.. IMHO using `perl` stdin/stdout would be faster...

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Apart from the date & time conversion awk is great for my task. But I will consider perl the next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call an external command like this:

```
awk '{
         cmd="date -d \""$0"\" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N"
         cmd | getline ts
         print $0, ts
         # awk opened a pipe for the communication with 
         # the command. close that pipe to avoid running
         # out of file descriptors
         close(cmd)
     }' <<< '16-FEB-2008 14:17:59.994669'
```

Output:

```
16-FEB-2008 14:17:59.994669 20080216141759994669000
```

---

Thanks to  dave_thompson_085's comment you can significantly improve the performance if you have `date` from GNU coreutils and `gawk`. GNU's `date` supports reading dates from stdin and `gawk` supports co-processes which allows to start a single instance of `date` in the background, write into it's stdin and read from stdout:

```
{
    cmd = "stdbuf -oL date -f /dev/stdin +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N"
    print $0 |& cmd 
    cmd |& getline ts
    print $0, ts
}
```

Note that you need to use the stdbuf command in addition to force `date` to output the results line by line.

Comment: Thanks, I was super confused about how to use the piping and getline to achieve this. This was very helpful!

Comment: I remember that I was also very confused when using it the first time ;) You are welcome

Comment: Since `-d` requires GNU coreutils `date` anyway, if reasonably recent you could use `-f /dev/stdin` and pipe a whole series of values to one process, much less inefficient. In GNU awk you could use `|&` but in any awk you could just combine a fifo/named-pipe plus standard `getline` or `print[f]` piping whichever is convenient.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Added that. Works nicely but `stdbuf` was required. Otherwise `cmd |& getline ts` would hang.

Comment: There's no need to call `date` just to rearrange characters in a string, and if you were going to use gawk for `|& "date"` then you should just use gawks builtin time functions instead.

Comment: Usually it is not a good idea to manually manipulate date and time strings, but I agree that it is ok in this example (and voted for the answer which is suggesting that). Anyhow I think the coprocess execution can be useful in many related use cases. Btw, which of gawk's time functions do you have in mind?

Answer (score 5):

Converting month names to numbers in awk is easy, and so is the reformatting as long as you don't need the (additional) validation `date` does 'for free':

```
$ echo this 16-FEB-2008 14:17:59.994669 that \
> | awk '{ split($2,d,"-"); split($3,t,"[:.]"); 
    m=sprintf("%02d",index("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC",d[2])/4+1);
    print $1,d[3] m d[1] t[1] t[2] t[3] t[4] "000",$4 }'
this 20080216141759994669000 that
$ # or can put the script in a file and use with awk -f
$ # or the whole thing in a shebang file like #!/bin/awk -f
```

This is not much longer than the code to run `date` and much more efficient for 'millions of lines'.

Comment: This is very good feedback. I might do something like this after all. Thanks for this and all your other comments.

Answer (score 2):

Using perl:

```
LANG=C perl -MTime::Piece -plE 's/\b(\d+-\w{3}-\d{4}\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)\.(\d+)\b/Time::Piece->strptime($1,q{%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S})->strftime(q{%Y%m%d%H%M%S}).$2/ge' < in >out
```

Replaces each time-like pattern globally with the re-formatted (and validated) date.

The core module [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) doesn't support fractional seconds, so a solution is a bit hackish...

Answer (score 2):

Many good answers here. Here's one that uses an `awk` *helper function* to reformat the dates.

```
awk '
  BEGIN { 
    mi["JAN"]="01"; mi["FEB"]="02"; mi["MAR"]="03"; mi["APR"]="04"; mi["MAY"]="05"; mi["JUN"]="06"
    mi["JUL"]="07"; mi["AUG"]="08"; mi["SEP"]="09"; mi["OCT"]="10"; mi["NOV"]="11"; mi["DEC"]="12"
  }
  function reformatDate(dtStr, tmStr) {
    split(dtStr, dtParts, "-"); gsub(/[:.]/, "", tmStr)
    return dtParts[3] mi[dtParts[2]] sprintf("%02d", dtParts[1]) tmStr "000"
  }
  { print reformatDate($1, $2) }
' <<<'16-FEB-2008 14:17:59.994669'
```

Answer (score 1):

here there is no need to invoke date, you just need a month lookup

```
$ awk -F'[- :.]' -v OFS='' '
     BEGIN {split("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC",m);
            for(i=1;i<=12;i++) a[m[i]]=i<10?"0"i:i}
           {$2=a[$2]; y=$3; $3=$1; $1=y; print $0 "000"}' file
```